# Specifying content-type for static resources in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Using the built-in Nuxt server, I would like to serve the static file `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` with content-type `application/json`. However, as the file doesn't have a `.json` file extension the content-type is returned as `application/octet-stream`. Is it possible to set some specific config for this file/route to return the content-type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After examining the source of [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) and then looking at the source of the [nuxt.js static file integration](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/packages/server/src/server.js#L94) I eventually figured it out.

I added the following property to `nuxt.config.js`:

```
    render: {
        static: {
            setHeaders: (resp, path) => {
                if (
                    resp.req.originalUrl ===
                    '/.well-known/apple-app-site-association'
                ) {
                    resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                }
            },
        },
    }
```

This property is [referenced in the nuxt.js docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-render/#static) but not from the [static directory docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static#static-directory).